# unable to access admin media folder

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, apache2

I have deployed my application on apache 2.2.21

In my settings.py file i have given like this

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'\\media'
MEDIA_URL = '/mymedia/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

i am getting admin style as we run 127.0.0.1:8000/admin(django server)

but unable to get admin style when running on apache

http.conf of apache i have only mentioned as follows

```
WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/myapp/django.wsgi

<Directory C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/myapp>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

is there any changes or anything else i have missed here please advise me,
thank you,

Comment: Where are you setting the serving of the media URLs, i.e. urls.py, Apache rewrite, symlink?

Comment: in my urls.py i am using the two lines                       (r'^mymedia/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  
        {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

Comment: Why, since that's very clearly documented as only working in debug mode and not for deployment?

Comment: Why don't you use Apache to handle the static files instead? See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot ' in MEDIA_ROOT line.

Ok, then try to add this in your apache conf:

```
<Location "/mymedia/">  
    SetHandler None
</Location>

<Location "/static/">  
    SetHandler None
</Location>

<LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png)$">  
    SetHandler None
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: no no, it is working both apache localhost and django server, but the styling is missing in apache

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apache to serve the static content instead of Django:

```
Alias /static/ /path/to/static/dir/
```

Comment: i have entered these lines in http.conf                             Alias /static/ C:/Python27/Lib/sitepackages/django/contrib/admin/media/

    <Directory "C:/Python27/Lib/sitepackages/django/contrib/admin/media">
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Directory>